# Any other ways to take info from Instagram API without logging in?

Tags: python, parsing, security, instagram-api

**Problem**: is here any ways to keep my login and password away from the code of a program (the program parse Instagram post info) that will be used by users? The code below takes info of the post, BUT if i make many requests to Instagram, it doesn't work. So i need to login in anyway `instagram_web_api.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)`, but my program will be used by another users.

**Question**: If my program will be used by another users, how can i hide my login and password from the code? I mean the program will be Desktop GUI, using code below partly, so users wouldn't see the code, BUT if they somehow look in the code, i want my login and password be hidden. Any ways, please?

**Code**:

```
...
    def _parse_instagram_post(self):
        instagram_web_api = Client()
        instagram_web_api.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)

        media_pk = instagram_web_api.media_pk_from_url(POST_URL)
        post_info = instagram_web_api.media_info(media_pk)
...
```

Comment: either the user has to supply credentials or you have to proxy requests on a server which holds the credentials

Comment: @JakobF, thank you! But what about the second way, is it enough hard to make a server and make request every time on it to get credentials? Can you give some advices how to start with that please?

Comment: Can you encrypt your login/password in another file? You could have `**kwargs` where depending on what you include will cause the function to fetch `LOGIN` and `PASSWORD` in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **Telegram Bot API**

**Why ?**

- Customers cannot access the source code.
- More useful and easy

But if you don't prefer this way, you can

- Obfuscate
- Encrypt
- Compile

your code.

I can suggest a few tools for these operations:

- https://www.pyinstaller.org/
- https://github.com/astrand/pyobfuscate
- https://github.com/PyObfx/PyObfx
- https://github.com/pycrypt123/pycryptor